# Dont'tknow why this problem happening and Cant Figure this out solution.can anyone solve this?

Tags: c, ubuntu, operating-system, computer-science, producer-consumer

This is an example code of produce consumer problems.
In Line 58,86,116,166,194 In function ‘void* Producer1(void*)’error: cast from ‘void*’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive].
still don't know why this error happening and can't figure out its solution.

I Use Ubuntu as an operating system and g++ -pthread library function to solve this.
code is here:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
//#include </usr/include/semaphore.h>

// for sleep
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE   5           /* total number of slots */

typedef struct                //Producing queue
{
    char buf1[BUFF_SIZE];   /* shared var */
    int in1;               /* buf[in%BUFF_SIZE] is the first empty slot */
    int out1;              /* buf[out%BUFF_SIZE] is the first full slot */
    sem_t full;           /* keep track of the number of full spots */
    sem_t empty;          /* keep track of the number of empty spots */

    // use correct type here
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;          /* enforce mutual exclusion to shared data */
} sbuf_t1;

typedef struct               //Chokolate Cake queue
{
    char buf2[BUFF_SIZE];   /* shared var */
    int in2;               /* buf[in%BUFF_SIZE] is the first empty slot */
    int out2;              /* buf[out%BUFF_SIZE] is the first full slot */
    sem_t full;           /* keep track of the number of full spots */
    sem_t empty;          /* keep track of the number of empty spots */

    // use correct type here
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;          /* enforce mutual exclusion to shared data */
} sbuf_t2;

typedef struct               //Vanilla Cake queue
{
    char buf3[BUFF_SIZE];   /* shared var */
    int in3;               /* buf[in%BUFF_SIZE] is the first empty slot */
    int out3;              /* buf[out%BUFF_SIZE] is the first full slot */
    sem_t full;           /* keep track of the number of full spots */
    sem_t empty;          /* keep track of the number of empty spots */

    // use correct type here
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;          /* enforce mutual exclusion to shared data */
} sbuf_t3;

sbuf_t1 shared1;
sbuf_t2 shared2;
sbuf_t3 shared3;


void *Producer1(void *arg)
{
    int i, index;
    char item;

    index = (int)arg;
  
    for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        sem_wait(&shared1.empty);    //down called in this line
        pthread_mutex_lock(&shared1.mutex);     //acquired mutex lock now it can produced no contex will be switched 
        sleep(1);  
        shared1.buf1[shared1.in1] = 'C'; //item pusch in buffer like item[in] = item;
        shared1.in1 = (shared1.in1+1)%BUFF_SIZE;  //queue operation q = (in + 1) % buff_size
        printf("[P%d] Producing Chokolate Cake...\n", index);
        fflush(stdout);
        /* Release the buffer */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared1.mutex); // unclock the mutex 
        /* Increment the number of full slots */
        sem_post(&shared1.full);  //buffer is full 
        //if (i % 2 == 1) sleep(1);
    }


    return NULL;
}


void *Producer2(void *arg)
{
    int i, index;
    char item;

    index = (int)arg;
    

    for(i=0; i<10; ++i)
    {
        item = i;
        sem_wait(&shared1.empty);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&shared1.mutex);
        sleep(1);
        shared1.buf1[shared1.in1] = 'V';
        shared1.in1 = (shared1.in1+1)%BUFF_SIZE;
        printf("[P%d] Producing Vanilla Cake...\n", index);
        fflush(stdout);
        /* Release the buffer */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared1.mutex);
        /* Increment the number of full slots */
        sem_post(&shared1.full);
        //if (i % 2 == 1) sleep(1);
    }


    return NULL;
}


void *Chef_Z(void *arg)
{
    int i, index;
    char item;

    index = (int)arg;

    for (i=10; i > 0; i--) {
        sem_wait(&shared1.full);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&shared1.mutex);
        sleep(1);
        item=shared1.buf1[shared1.out1];
        if(item == 'C')  // Chokolate Cake queue
        {
        sem_wait(&shared2.full);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&shared2.mutex);
            shared2.buf2[shared2.in2]=item; 
            shared2.in2 = (shared2.in2+1)%BUFF_SIZE;
        printf("[C_Z] Consuming  Chokolate Cake and stored it in Chokolate queue ...\n");
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared2.mutex);
            /* Increment the number of full slots */
            sem_post(&shared2.empty);

        }
        else if(item == 'V')  // Vanilla Cake queue
        {
        sem_wait(&shared3.full);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&shared3.mutex);
            shared3.buf3[shared3.in3]=item; 
            shared3.in3 = (shared3.in3+1)%BUFF_SIZE;
        printf("[C_Z] Consuming  Vanilla Cake and stored it in Vanilla queue ...\n");
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared3.mutex);
            /* Increment the number of full slots */
            sem_post(&shared3.empty);

        }
        shared1.out1 = (shared1.out1+1)%BUFF_SIZE;

        fflush(stdout);
        /* Release the buffer */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared1.mutex);
        /* Increment the number of full slots */
        sem_post(&shared1.empty);

        /* Interleave  producer and consumer execution */
        //if (i % 2 == 1) sleep(1);
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *Waiter1(void *arg) //Chokolate cake waiter
{
    int i, index;
    char item;

    index = (int)arg;
    
    for (i=10; i > 0; i--) {
        sem_wait(&shared2.full);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&shared2.mutex);
        sleep(1);

        item=shared2.buf2[shared2.out2];
        shared2.out2 = (shared2.out2+1)%BUFF_SIZE;
        printf("[W%d] Consuming  Chokolate Cake ...\n", index);
        fflush(stdout);
        /* Release the buffer */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared2.mutex);
        /* Increment the number of full slots */
        sem_post(&shared2.empty);

        /* Interleave  producer and consumer execution */
        //if (i % 2 == 1) sleep(1);
    }
    return NULL;
}


void *Waiter2(void *arg)  // Vanilla cake waiter
{
    int i, index;
    char item;

    index = (int)arg;
    

    for (i=10; i > 0; i--) {
        sem_wait(&shared3.full);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&shared3.mutex);
        sleep(1);

        item=shared3.buf3[shared3.out3];
        shared3.out3 = (shared3.out3+1)%BUFF_SIZE;
        printf("[W%d] Consuming  Vanilla Cake ...\n", index);
        fflush(stdout);
        /* Release the buffer */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared3.mutex);
        /* Increment the number of full slots */
        sem_post(&shared3.empty);

        /* Interleave  producer and consumer execution */
        //if (i % 2 == 1) sleep(1);
    }

    return NULL;
}


int main()
{
    //pthread_t idP, idC;
    pthread_t thread1,thread2,thread3,thread4,thread5;
    int index;

    void *producer1End;
    void *producer2End;
    void *chef_zEnd;
    void *waiter1End;
    void *waiter2End;

    sem_init(&shared1.full, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&shared1.empty, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
    pthread_mutex_init(&shared1.mutex, NULL);

    sem_init(&shared2.full, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&shared2.empty, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
    pthread_mutex_init(&shared2.mutex, NULL);

    sem_init(&shared3.full, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&shared3.empty, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
    pthread_mutex_init(&shared3.mutex, NULL);

    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, Producer1, (void*)1 );
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, Producer2, (void*)2 );
    pthread_create(&thread3, NULL, Chef_Z, (void*)1 );    

    pthread_create(&thread4, NULL, Waiter1, (void*)1);
    pthread_create(&thread5, NULL, Waiter2, (void*)2);

    pthread_join(thread1,&producer1End);
    pthread_join(thread2,&producer2End);
    pthread_join(thread3,&chef_zEnd);
    pthread_join(thread4,&waiter1End);
    pthread_join(thread5,&waiter2End);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Is it an error or a warning? `index = (int)arg;` it's telling you that it is technically incorrect to cast a pointer (which is what `arg` is) into an `int` because a pointer and an `int` may be of different sizes. Either ignore the warning or make `index` an `intptr_t` type.

Comment: Thanks for your response kaylum. it's an error. I use intptr_t also but it still not working.

Comment: Please give exactly what you changed and the exact error. If you did it correctly it should not have that error. Also, please don't just dump the entire code. Remove all code not related to the problem as there is alot there that is not relevant to the actual issue. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Here Is The Full Code: https://ideone.com/klevq9 .I use ubuntu  terminal and  g++ -pthread library to solve this, and the error is happening on 58,86,116,166,194 line and  the error is "n function ‘void* Producer1(void*)’ error: cast from ‘void*’ to ‘int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]" .thank you.

Comment: No, code needs to be in the question. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67846037/edit) the post tp update it. And the error `void*’ to ‘int` shows you did not change to `intptr_t` as you claim you did or you did not correctly build the updated version.

Comment: `int i, index;` There, you did not actually change the type as you were advised to. Should be `intptr_t index;`

Comment: I have changed the code according to ur advice (code here: https://ideone.com/xwCtHX ).now there is no error but the program is not showing any output.

Comment: Please add a meaningful and contextual title to your question.

Comment: Thanks Swag2198 For your response. the problem has been solved.